# How to access a file copied from s3 bucket to elastic beanstalk inside .NET code?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am hosting a .NET backend app on Elastic Beanstalk. I made a config file like:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["my-bucket"]
          roleName:
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
files:
  # Private key
  "/var/app/current/file":
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://my-url/file
```

This seems to work, however, when I try to access the file in .NET by just using `file` (I have also tried `./file`) as the path name, I get `File not found` error. It says my current directory is `var/app/current`.

I am ultimately unsure how I can even see the files in the ec2 for the EB instance to even see if it copied over, or failed without throwing an exception. And if it did copy over, where it is being put... Or am I just accessing the file wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EB is going to **overwrite** your `/var/app/current` at the end of your deployment. So whatever you write that in `files`, gets deleted. You can try with `/var/app/staging`. If this also does not work, you can consider keeping your files outside of `/var/app`.

Comment: Thank you!! I've been going against this brick wall for days trying to figure out how to get this working. I had two problems: 1) I moved the file to the top level (just "/file"). I could now find it!! But couldn't access. 2) Had to update mode to 755 to give proper permissions. But problem two was easy once I could finally find the file thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: @TylerDahle did your file end up in your `/var/app/current` directory at all or did it just sit somewhere else on the elastic beanstalk instance? I'm having a similar issue.